# Is there any bonus for being Commander?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

I just started playing and I see people who are way higher level than me. I was wondering if you get a sort of XP bonus for being Commander or if Commanders could get XP easier than soldiers?

Comment: As an aside: Don't play commander before you are at least level 30 so you know what players need from the commander (when they need supply, how many supplies are neccessary and where spawns are good or where you get stuck in a spawn) and practice against bots until you have the basics down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get experience if your team follows your orders (if you give them orders via the interface). Otherwise it's mostly just from kills via turrets or commander abilities.

You often get XP for "Commander support" even without giving orders, though i haven't quite figured out why, i think it's related to your team capping stuff.

Basically, to max XP for everyone, give a lot of orders (and remember to remove them again later) and you and your team will get XP for following those orders.